# Nested JSON with objects and arrays, find value

Tags: json, reactjs

Im building a React app and I have a quite complex JSON file where I need to find and output certain values of an object in an array.

Im trying to output all my people from my JSON, they look something like this:

```
people: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": [
            {
                "street": "Kulas Light",
                "type": "house",
                "attribute": {
                    "sketch": "sketch.jpg",
                    "photo": "photo.jpg"
                }
            },
            {
                "street": "Lorem Ipsum",
                "type": "apartment",
                "attribute": {
                    "sketch": "sketch.jpg",
                    "photo": "photo.jpg"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have no problem to output the email, doing it like so:

```
var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        results: {}
    }
},
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL) // fetch from API, returns JSON
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {this.setState(
        { results: data.people}
        );
    })
},
renderResult : function(key){
    return <Result key={key} index={key} details={this.state.results[key]}/>
},
render : function() {
    return (
        <ul>
            {Object.keys(this.state.results).map(this.renderResult)}
        </ul>
    )
}
});

var Result = React.createClass({
render : function() {
    return (
      <li>
          {this.props.details.email}

          <img src="{this.props.details.address.type=house.attribute.photo}"/>
      </li>

    )
}
});

ReactDOM.render(App, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

However, now I need to output "photo" but only for "type": "house". I tried this but no luck, well aware that this is way off. Im quite new to handling JSON data and React and Google hasn't helped me even after a few hours of trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `.address` property isn't an object but an array of objects so
>   `.type` is not available directly on `.address`:

```
this.state.results.people.address.type
//  .type property doesn't exist on array
```

---

**Solution:**

You can use Array.prototype.filter on `.address` to obtain an array of objects that have a property `type` whose value is "house":

```
var houseAddresses = this.state.results.people.address.filter(function(value){
  return value.type === "house";
});
```

Here, houseAddress will be an array of objects whose `type` value is 'house".

You can then loop through the array to create the relevant JSX using `for`, [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  The following example uses Array#map:

```
const houseImgTags = houseAddresses.map(function(house, index){
  return (
    <img
      src={house.attribute.photo}
      key={'house'+index}
    />
  );
});
```

*(A key was added here in case there are more than one instance of a `house` object)*

Comment: Ah i see what you are doing, but I cant really get it to work. There are errors while trying to compiling the code.

This logs all objects:

`var houseAddresses = this.props.details.address;`

This causes compiling error: 

 `var houseAddresses = this.props.details.address.filter((value){
   value.type === "house";
  });`

Comment: @dilla: needs the `function` keyword when declaring the function passed to filter: `this.state.results.people.address.filter(function(value){
      return value.type === "house";
    });`

Comment: Ah that fixed it, cool and thanks for your help man! Im not fully there though, cant manage to implement it in my component that renders all info such as email and street. If you have time and want to, id just want to ask if you could check my code privately? It's a about 70 rows.

Comment: Is there a reason you removed the chosen answer/did not up-vote?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: If you have time, wanna help me implement your solution in my original code (edited original post)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write.
`<img src={this.states.results.address.type==="house"?house.attribute.photo : otherwise_photo}/>`
Basically this would compare address.type is house or not,then return the result corresponded.

Comment: There is no `type` property on `this.states.results.address`, **it's an array that contains objects that do have the `type` property**